# Microsoft bot options are not clickable

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

I am using bot Microsoft bot builder sample. But if the string length of choices is more then the choices are not clickable. How to make it as clickable or is there any method for the clickable or buttons for the options. I am using the node sample.

[This sample I am using](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/06.using-cards)

Comment: Can you explain a little bit what are you trying to accomplish? Post some example code so we can understand the problem

Comment: What channel are you using? Saying Emulator doesn't help btw, because you're not planning on having your users talk to your bot through Emulator. (Since there are multiple people on this thread, you will have to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @Koushik - Are you still working on this?